# Error: UNKNOWN with Meteor app on MacOSX

Tags: meteor, future

When I run my meteor app located in /path/to/app, it correctly builds and starts, but after about 45 seconds to 1 minute it will always crash with an error like

```
=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
=> Started your app.

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/

/Users/alex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1j76dru++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:278
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
Error: UNKNOWN, readdir '/path/to/node_modules/sjcl/jsdoc_toolkit-2.3.3-beta/app/test'
    at Object.Future.wait (/Users/alex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1j76dru++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:398:15)
    at /tools/fs/files.js:1331:28
    at Object.wrapper (/tools/fs/files.js:1334:20)
    at readDirectory (/tools/fs/watch.js:265:26)
    at Watcher._fireIfDirectoryChanged (/tools/fs/watch.js:409:23)
    at /tools/fs/watch.js:670:12
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/alex/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1j76dru++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
    at Watcher._checkDirectories (/tools/fs/watch.js:659:7)
    at new Watcher (/tools/fs/watch.js:356:10)
    at [object Object]._.extend._runOnce (/tools/runners/run-app.js:746:23)
    at [object Object]._.extend._fiber (/tools/runners/run-app.js:858:28)
    at /tools/runners/run-app.js:396:12
    - - - - -
```

Let's say I try to reproduce this error a couple times, I will will always see the same error at future.js:278 and the Object.Future.wait at 398:15, but the directory that's trying to be read by readdir will be some different node_modules package. I have all the permissions correct for this project.

It might be useful to know that prior to this problem I was experiencing a problem with too many file open (an EMFILE error) and I added this line to my bashrc file to increase number of files a process could have open

```
sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 16384 16384 && ulimit -n 16384
```

which got rid of the EMFILE error, but now I'm stuck with this unknown error.

Also, I've tried to solution here

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4660

with "sudo purge" but it didn't work. Any solutions to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Finding and then killing any other running instances of Meteor seemed to fix this for me:

```
ps -x | grep meteor
# find [pid] of meteor instance
kill [pid]
```

Answer (score 1):

Run `sudo purge`. If it doesn't work, restart you mac, then run meteor again. It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that raising `maxfiles` limits way higher solves the problem.

For example:

```
sudo launchctl limit maxfiles 100000 100000
```